# Using different levels of comments in Python

Tags: python, comments, pep8

I often find myself writing code with different levels of comments, for example

```
# Comment about "Doing A"
...

## Comment about "Doing part 1 of A"
...

## Comment about "Doing part 2 of A"
...

# Comment about "Doing B"
...
```

Now I had an inclination that this was considered wrong, however it always made sense to me and helped when reading past code. Since recently using `pylint` to check my code it complains as I expected it might, that I should not use more than one `#`.

What is an alternative to help me keep the readability of the different comment levels, without actually using them?

Comment: Break down your code into smaller functions until you no longer need multiple levels of comments?

Comment: Unless you have a team that has an agreed-upon standard for comments, I would just ignore `pylint`'s opinion on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Its mostly personal choice, but this is what I do.

For major sections, use a block comment like this:

```
########################################################################
#                               Doing A                                #
########################################################################
```

While for subsections, I use a single line comment like this

```
#-------------------------Doing part 1 of A----------------------------#
```